# read XML from URL and secure it

Tags: c#, .net, xml, security, xml-parsing

I have a general question and its about security. 
i have my own web application and i want to show data from another website by reading its XML.

But its not secure to parse XML from extern resource, the page my contain harmful script or something. 
What to do that parsing xml and avoid all scripts that may harm my site.

this is my parsing but its not secure!

```
        XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.Load(url);
        XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/response/current_observation");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            string tempf = node["node1"].InnerText;
            string tempc = node["node2"].InnerText;


            label2.Text = tempf;
            label4.Text = tempc;
```

To read the data into a class, then show it in my application could be solution ??

Answer (score 2):

You can check this article : 
[How to prevent cross-site scripting security issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252985)

From the article:

---

### The problem

The underlying problem is that many Web pages display input that is not validated. If input is not validated, malicious script can be embedded within the input. If a server-side script then displays this non-validated input, the script runs on the browser as though the trusted site generated it.

### Ramifications

If input to your dynamic Web pages is not validated, you may encounter the following problems:

- Data integrity can be compromised.
- Cookies can be set and read.
- User input can be intercepted.
- Malicious scripts can be executed by the client in the context of the
  trusted source.

Which Web pages are at risk? Essentially, the problem affects dynamic page creation based on input that was not validated. Typical examples include the following types of Web pages:

- Search engines that return results pages based on user input.
- Login pages that store user accounts in databases, cookies, and so
  forth and later write the user name out to the client.
- Web forms that process credit card information.

### Prevention

This section presents a few approaches to preventing cross-site scripting security attacks. Evaluate your specific situation to determine which techniques will work best for you. It is important to note that in all techniques, you are validating data that you receive from input and not your trusted script. Essentially, prevention means that you follow good coding practice by running sanity checks on your input to your routines.

The following list outlines the general approaches to prevent cross-site scripting attacks:

- Encode output based on input parameters.
- Filter input parameters for special characters.
- Filter output based on input parameters for special characters.

When you filter or encode, you must specify a character set for your Web pages to ensure that your filter is checking for the appropriate special characters. The data that is inserted into your Web pages should filter out byte sequences that are considered special based on the specific character set. A popular charset is ISO 8859-1, which was the default in early versions of HTML and HTTP. You must take into account localization issues when you change these parameters.

**Encode output based on input parameters for special characters**

Encode data that is received as input when you write it out as HTML. This technique is effective on data that was not validated for some reason during input. By using techniques such as `URLEncode` and `HTMLEncode`, you can prevent malicious script from executing.

The following code snippets demonstrate how to use `URLEncode` and `HTMLEncode` from Active Server Pages (ASP) pages:

```
<%
      var BaseURL = http://www.example.com/search2.asp?searchagain=;
      Response.write("<a href=\"" + BaseUrl +
      Server.URLEncode(Request.QueryString("SearchString")) +
      "\">click-me</a>");
%>
<% Response.Write("Hello visitor <I>" +
      Server.HTMLEncode(Request.Form("UserName")) +
      "</I>");
%>
```

If you encode the HTML and URLs, you may need to specify the code page as you would if you were to filter data.

It is important to note that calling `HTMLEncode` on the string that is about to be displayed will prevent any script in it from being executed and thus prevents the problem.
Filter input parameters for special characters

Filtering input works by removing some or all special characters from your input. Special characters are characters that enable script to be generated within an HTML stream. Special characters include the following:

```
< > " ' % ; ) ( & + -
```

Note that your individual situation may warrant the filtering of additional characters or strings beyond the special characters.

While filtering can be an effective technique, there are a few caveats:

- Filtering may not be appropriate for some input. For example, in
  scenarios where you are receiving  input from an HTML form, you
  may instead choose a method such as encoding (see below).
- Some filtered characters may actually be required input to
  server-side script.

The following sample filter, which is written in JavaScript, demonstrates how to remove special characters:

```
function RemoveBad(strTemp) { 
    strTemp = strTemp.replace(/\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g,""); 
    return strTemp;
}
```

The following code processes user input before storing it for later use.

```
<% Session("StoredPreference") = RemoveBad(Request.Cookies("UserColor"));
         var TempStr = RemoveBad(Request.QueryString("UserName"));
```

**Filter output based on input parameters for special characters**

This technique is similar to filtering input except that you filter characters that are written out to the client. While this can be an effective technique, it may present a problem for Web pages that write out HTML elements.

For example, on a page that writes out `<TABLE>` elements, a generic function that removes the special characters would strip the < and > characters, which ruins the `<TABLE>` tag. Therefore, in order for this technique to be useful, you would only filter data passed in or data that was previously entered by a user and stored in a database.

**Possible sources of malicious data**

While the problem applies to any page that uses input to dynamically generate HTML, the following are some possible sources of malicious data to help you spot check for potential security risks:

- Query String
- Cookies
- Posted data
- URLs and pieces of URLs, such as PATH_INFO
- Data retrieved from users that is persisted in some fashion such as
  in a database

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, the following are key points to remember regarding the cross-site scripting security problem:

- The problem affects dynamic page creation based on input that was not
  validated.
- Omission of a sanity check on input data can have unexpected security
  implications. The problem is preventable through good development
  standards such as input validation.
- You need to evaluate solutions on a per site, page, and even field
  basis and use a technique that makes sense.

---

Comment: @Luke I have edited the answer, including the essential parts of the link

Comment: @Luke  Where is the best place to do the validation. I mean When im reading from the URL to XMLDocument object, Or should i only validate element from XMLDoxument object when bringing it to the page ?

Comment: @LinaFarid Hi Lina, all I did was review Yazan's answer - I can't help with your problem I'm afraid as I am not knowledgeable in this area. If you have a different question then I would recommend you start a new question on the site.

Comment: mainly you can do the above answer to avoid any JavaScript injection. but i think you need to do more validation. more validation will dependents on many factors like your scope, business requirement, nature of data and business ..etc